# BOOL logs fine on simulator, but on iPhone logs numbers like 96, -32, etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, boolean

I'm working on an app that displays randomly chosen haiku from a list that comes with the app.  The user has the ability to mark a haiku as a "favorite" (and also to unmark it as such).  Everything works fine with the simulator, and NSLog shows the Boolean property `isFavorite` of each haiku as 0 or 1.

But when I run the app on the iPhone, NSLog shows the Boolean property sometimes as 0, sometimes as 1, sometimes as 96, sometimes as -32, without any correlation with whether the user has actually favorited the haiku. How can I fix this?

`EDIT:` Here's the code I'm using:

```
-(void)displayHaiku {
    [self.displayHaikuTextView removeFromSuperview];
    self.haiku = [[GHHaikuInstance alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Is haiku favorite? %d",self.haiku.isFavorite); 

        //On simulator the above line always logs 0 or 1, correlated exactly with whether the haiku has been marked "favorite."  On iPhone it could be any number, and shows no correlation.

    //Code that displays haiku onscreen.
}
```

`isFavorite` is a BOOL declared and synthesized in `GHHaikuInstance`, but it's only set to 1 if the user marks it as a favorite.  (In other words--I don't explicitly set it to 0; I'm just using default 0 until the user changes that to 1.)

Comment: are you sure you used %d ?

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: Just added code to clarify.

Comment: And isFavourite is defined as....?

Comment: Clarification added.  Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Your `GHHaikuInstance` init method should be explicitly setting the value of `isFavorite` to 0. I'm guessing you're not doing this. Declaring and synthesizing is not enough.

Comment: Thank you--that seems to have fixed the problem!  I'm curious, though--any idea why this should cause problems on the phone when it didn't on the simulator?

Comment: Declaring a variable just gives it memory on the stack. The variable isn't set to anything when it is declared which is why you're seeing the unexpected behavior. Results will vary from device to device based on how it handles memory allocation.

Comment: @bvogelzang It is not necessary to set instance variables to 0 in your init method! See [Apple's Objective-C docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW7): "The alloc method has one other important task, which is to clear out the memory allocated for the object’s properties by setting them to zero."

Comment: @JoelDerfner Can you post the code you've used to declare isFavorite? Perhaps it's a global or local by accident?

Comment: Please add everything from `GHHaikuInstance` connected to `favourite` property. Getter, setter, `@synthesize`, declaration etc.

Answer (score 3):

To log `BOOL` values you can use strings

```
NSLog(@"Is haiku favorite? %@", self.haiku.isFavorite ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: Hmm.  Well, this gets rid of the weird numbers, but still whether NSLog gives me "YES" or "NO" has no correlation to the actual value of `isFavorite`.  :(  Again--this is only on the phone.  It works fine on the simulator.

Comment: Based on your code you just init `GHHaikuInstance`, so log must be `NO`. What is difference between iPhone and simulator? Did you tried to clear and reinstall an app?

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends `%hhd`.

You can read more about [format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265fiers).

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the difference between Release and Debug version :))

(check "Optmization Level" setting. Debug version is set to None [-O0], while the Release version is set to Fastest, Smallest [-Os].) -  so ... different floating point behavior..

You MUST change your statement / init method from

```
BOOL isFavorite;
```

to

```
BOOL isFavorite = NO;
```